# Cannot login to Wordpress, password reset doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, authentication, passwords, reset-password

I cannot login to 2 of my WordPress sites (running on the same subdomain). After login I didn't get a message that my credentials are incorrect, but the page reloads and I'm back to the loginpage.

Password rest link doesn't work, he says 'invalid key'. Key = domain.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=k5ZhuvbXgAofh0Yql8VK&login=username

Password reset via database doesn't work too. Changed the password to the value given by http://www.passwordtool.hu/wordpress-password-hash-generator-v3-v4 (testtest), but I'm not able to login with the new username/password (still the same result: no error message)

I didn't changed anything to those website the last 2/3 weeks. Maybe an automatically update has changed something. Site urls are correct.

One site is running WP Limit Login Attempts (https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-limit-login-attempts/) which allows me to try 4 times before I been blocked for 30 minutes.

Deleted all cookies but no result. Has anybody an solution?

Comment: Not nearly enough information to answer.  Here's some questions to help us get the info we would need to help: 1. "password reset via database doesn't work".  What does that mean? How did you reset? Did you use MD5 when you reset? "Doesn't work" - meaning the password you try and login with doesn't allow a login?  2. "Invalid key" on your password reset link could be a few things.  Post a sample of what the key looks like (replace the domain name with "example.com").  3. No recent update to WP would cause this - are you running any security plugins such as WordFence, etc?

Comment: Sorry, added more information to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. It was/is a problem with my Internet Service Provider, which filters the internet (paid service, special for kids).

The filter is now off, and I can login to my sites.